# Add Additional Options to cart

Tags: magento2, custom-options, shopping-cart

I have tried to add the additional option to cart items directly in a custom controller. But the additional options not get saved in `quote_item_option` table.

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Mod\Controller\Checkout\Cart;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory;

class UpdateOptions extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var ItemFactory
     */
    protected $itemFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param ItemFactory $itemFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ItemFactory $itemFactory
    )
    {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
//        $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
        $itemFactory = $this->itemFactory->create()->load(145);
        $additionalOptions[] = [
                        'label' => "Custom Text",
                        'value' => "Custom value"
                    ];

        $optionArray = array(
            'code' => 'additional_options',
            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
        );

        $itemFactory->addOption($optionArray);
        $itemFactory->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add product with custom option and redirect to cart page ?